# How to convert bytes from file into an image - Java

Tags: java, image, swing, arraylist, byte

```
public static void saveMap(String fileName){
    ArrayList<byte[]> mapData = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < DrawPanel.cells.size(); i++){
        try {
            if(DrawPanel.cells.get(i).image != null){
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(DrawPanel.cells.get(i).image,"png",byteArrayOutputStream);
                byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                mapData.add(i,bytes);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("res/Saved Maps/"+fileName+".map"));
        for(int i = 0; i < mapData.size(); i++){
            fileOutputStream.write(mapData.get(i));
        }
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It takes the image from each cell (a JPanel), converts it into bytes and adds it to an array list. It then writes the array list to a file.
My question is, how do I go about reversing this? So that I can get each image into it's respective cell.

Comment: Note that writing to application resources will fail when you run from a .jar file, because the resources are entries in the .jar archive and are not files at all.

Comment: Is it me, or does this question smell like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is concept of Serializable Object in Java SE1.7 which states:

> To serialize an object means to convert its state to a byte stream so that the byte stream can be reverted back into a copy of the object. A Java object is serializable if its class or any of its superclasses implements either the `java.io.Serializable` interface or its subinterface, `java.io.Externalizable`. Deserialization is the process of converting the serialized form of an object back into a copy of the object. (Extracted from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html)).

`ArrayList` implements `java.io.Serializable` ([ArrayList JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)), therefore all elements stored are serialized.

In this case in particular, you might use instead:

```
// Serialize the ArrayList mapData
try (OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("res/Saved Maps/"+fileName+".map");
        OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);) {
    output.writeObject(mapData);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error ocurred: " + ex.getMessage());
}

// Deserialize the 'fileName'.map file
try (InputStream file = new FileInputStream("'fileName'.map");
        InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(file);
        ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(buffer);) {
    // Deserialize the ArrayList (serialized on this file)
    ArrayList<byte[]> recoveredMapData = (ArrayList<byte[]>) input.readObject();
    // Display its data
    for (byte[] cell_byte : recoveredMapData) {
        System.out.println("=> " + cell_byte);
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error ocurred: " + ex.getMessage());
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error ocurred: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

See this [topic](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=57) for implementations on both Java SE1.6 and Java SE1.7.